# How do I download The Wolf Among Us Episode 2 without paying again?

Tags: xbox-360, the-wolf-among-us

I have the season pass on Xbox 360 for *The Wolf Among Us*.

Episode 2 of this is listed as available for download in-game and it's release has been widely publicised in the press.

However, when I select the "Download" option in-game, it keeps taking me to the payment dialog where it wants to charge me £3.99.

How can I download the second episode without paying for it again?

Comment: I know it might sound obvious, but have you got the season pass downloaded onto your Xbox?

Comment: @deutschZuid Yes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a known issue on the Microsoft end affecting many titles. Stay tuned for info. Source - [TellTaleGames website](http://www.telltalegames.com/community/discussion/58200/xbox360-season-pass-not-working).

There's a statement on the [Microsoft support website](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-live-status):

> Xbox members, do you own a "The Wolf Among Us" Season Pass but are being asked to pay for "Episode 2: Smoke & Mirrors?"  Our team is engaged and working to have a fix out for you tomorrow.

So hopefully this should be resolved soon.

Comment: Could you provide a link to back this up?

Comment: Just thinking out aloud here. What if someone mistakenly purchased it without looking, thinking that it was free? Do they get a refund...

Comment: @deutschZuid Maybe if they contacted Xbox CS and asked, they would. But the Xbox CS isn't particularly helpful in general, so I'm not going to test it.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft just sent me a free code for episode 2. You should check and see if they sent you one as well.

Answer (score 3):

I experienced the same problem, and the solution is quite counter-intuitive.

First, if you try to go into the "downloadable content" menu in the game interface, it will show that you own the Season Pass and that you have not yet downloaded Episode 2.  If you select Episode 2, it will ask you to pay.  Do *not* do this.

Instead, check your messages through the guide interface, and you should have one from "Xbox Live" - mine read:

> You bought The Wolf Among Us Season Pass and didn’t receive Episode 2: Smoke and Mirrors! Here’s your free code XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX to redeem for Episode 2 at account.Xbox.com or on your console.

If you got this, great.  My first instinct was to enter it on the Xbox.com site's "Redeem Code" page.  This added the content to my account but **did not download it, and did not give me credit for "buying" it in the in-game DLC menu.**

In order to download it, do *not* go through the in-game DLC interface.  From the dashboard, go all the way to the right.  Choose "Account" then "Download History" - you may have to scroll this list, but you should find "Wolf Among Us Episode 2" here.  Pick it, and then select "Download Again"

There's also an option from the in-game DLC menu, when attempting to "purchase" Episode 2, where you can change your payment type.  This menu will allow you to enter a code.  I don't know if entering the code from the "Xbox Live" message will work, but it might be worth a shot to save a step or two.

**Update:**  Just got an email from Telltale directly, confirming the above steps:

> Once you receive your console system message with the redemption code for The Wolf Among Us Episode 2: Smoke & Mirrors, please follow these instructions to acquire the content:
>
> Go to either Xbox.com/My Account to redeem your code or Settings/Account/Redeem Code on your Xbox 360 console and input the code.
>
> Once your code is redeemed please to go to Download History under Account on your Xbox 360 console to download The Wolf Among Us Episode 2: Smoke & Mirrors . After your download is complete you will be able to launch Episode 2 from within The Wolf Among Us.

...so, you may wish to check the email address associated with the Xbox Live account you used to purchase the Season Pass as well.